# mkdocs search bar is not working after building site

Tags: markdown, documentation, mkdocs

The **search bar** on the site is not working after building MKDOCS. Whereas when I serve in localhost it's working.

Is there any workaround for this to make use of the search bar after building mkdocs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search only works when the site is served from a server. It does not work when you are viewing the files using `file://`. This is a limitation imposed by your browser's security settings (the JavaScript code cannot access the `search-index.json` file over `file://`) and I do not recommend that you disable those settings. You may find a third-party plugin and/or theme which provides a workaround by recreating the index file in a different format so that it can be loaded via a `<script>` tag rather than an ajax request.

Comment: This does not respond to the question. I have the same problem: using `mkdocs serve` search is ok, while after `mkdocs build` + copy on apache server, search on http link does nothing.

Comment: @EdouardThiel if search is not working when serving from a third party server, then that is a completely different issue that the one being discussed here.

Comment: yes, but I thought that was the question. I have posted a solution for an Apache server.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution, working on an Apache server:

add to the root of your `site/` a file `.htaccess` containing the line:

```
AddType application/javascript .js
```

A same kind of solution for an Azure Web App can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66131060/1788851).