# MKDOCS Material theme Search capability not working

Tags: material-ui, mkdocs

I set up an MKDOCS site with the 'material' theme and am hosting it using an Azure Web App.  The site works perfectly on the local host, but on Azure web app, the search bar doesn't work.  It shows 'Initializing search' when you put the cursor in the search field.  I tried adding this to the .yaml file, and it did not fix the issue:

```
plugins:
    - search:
        lang: en
```

I am using MKDOCS 1.1.2 and material 6.2.8

[image: initSearchscreenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the fix on Github:
https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/1468

Create a web.config file and post it to the WWW root on the server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: A same kind of solution for an Apache server can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66638644/1788851).

Answer (score 0):

For IIS server by adding MimeType has resolved the issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31039903)